# Is SQL Server Timestamp deprecated and what to use in replacement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp

The [T-SQL MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) page states

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated.
>   This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature.

Does this mean to suggest that the SQL Server Timestamp data type is also deprecated as well? If so, what should be used to replace it, as the SQL Server DateTime data type is not granular enough to ensure high transactional records can be stamped with a unique value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That same page says to use `rowversion` instead of `timestamp`. The deprecation is the syntax, not the underlying mechanism. Can you imagine them removing support for such a widely-used feature? Fugghedaboudit.

Comment: Cheers, that's largely what I thought. Thanks for the clarification.